# Mapbox with React - should I use Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I don't particularly like the complexity that redux adds to a react app, so I try to avoid it as much as I can. I always struggle to know if I need redux or not anyway.

I am building a single web app with react, which consist of a map (Mapbox). I have arrived to the point where I struggle to pass data from/to non-related components while keeping my code clean.

So, I am wondering, is this a sign for redux to come into the game? Knowning that I am not a react master, and that there might be other solutions, such as context.

What do you think? Do you use redux for your Mapbox app? If yes, for which purpose?

Comment: "I struggle to pass data from/to non-related components while keeping my code clean" leads me to say yes, it's time.  But you are really asking an opinion question here.

Comment: You could look into React context you mentioned, or an alternative to Redux like e.g. [MobX](https://mobx.js.org/).

Comment: Well, from what I read, React Context is only to pass data from parent to children. Thanks for MobX, I did not know it, it sounds interesting, I might use it instead of redux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah I would, React Redux is not particularly difficult to set up. You will find it very useful if youre mapbox app requires user authentication.

Comment: Why yould it be more useful for user authentication. I already have an authentication process, am I missing somethoing useful here?

Comment: user auth is difficult in a single page app, redux makes it easier and more secure. I use redux because there are a lot of hacks and problems with user auth in a single page app, redux just helps more. You can also do things like save the user profile info and use it in other areas of app.

Answer (score 1):

mapbox has an open source redux wrapper here if its useful https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-redux